# Outgoing Calls Twillio Client

Tags: twilio

I"m trying to have two phones call each other in the same way Uber does via Twillio:

FROM: Client A calls from their mobile device, and the number they are calling shows up as my Twillio number

TO: Client B gets a call from Client A, but the number shows up as my Twilio number to prevent

However I keep getting an error `11200 - HTTP retrieval failureArchive`

Error returns a 406 for what thats worth

I don't understand why I even need this `url` ! I just want to connect the calls!

**ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):**

In my controller

```
def make_twillio_call
account_sid = ENV["twllio_account_sid"]
auth_token = ENV["twillio_auth_token"]
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
url_string = "http://myapp.com/customers/Dial_Twillio.xml"

@call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => ENV["TWILIO_MOBILE"],
    # :from => params[:From].to_s,
    :to => params[:To],
    :url => url_string
)
respond_to do |format|
  msg = {:status => "SUCCESS", :token => "Call connected"}
  format.json  { render :json => msg } # don't do msg.to_json
  end
end
```

**Customer/Dial_Twillio.xml.erb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
</Response>
```

Comment: @philnash this may be up your alley. Simmilar to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419182/can-i-make-a-call-from-application-to-personal-mobile-number-by-using-the-twilio` but from clients mobile phone to another phone

Comment: You called? I'll see what I can do!

Comment: @philnash I'm actually gettin a different error. If you're free might be more constructive to move this to chat and I'll post a summary here. your docs could use some more ruby !

Comment: Just answering your first part right now, let's see how far that gets us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do some call forwarding with privacy here. The first part of the call should be user A dialling your Twilio number.

Then, instead of using the REST API as it looks like you are doing right now, you should respond with some TwiML to tell Twilio to forward the call to user B. So, you controller action would look a bit like this:

```
def forward_call
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial :callerId => YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER do |d|
      d.Number USER_B_NUMBER
    end
  end
  render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

Then you need to make sure that your Twilio number's voice URL points towards this action.

I've included the callerId as your Twilio number here, which means that it will be the number that shows up on User B's phone when it rings.

Does this help?

Comment: I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments 1 for 0` error in `each_key`.

Comment: Which line causes that error, can you show the stack trace up until it shows a line in your controller?

Comment: The `render xml :response` which is what I figured. Trying to do a respond_to.

Comment: Excellent! I thought Rails would try to run `to_xml` on the object anyway. Glad you've got it sorted.